# Role permissions with keycloak instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a keycloak instance which I use for CRUD operations with roles. Is there any way to get role permissions? I ve tried to search eveerything about it, but I cant find how to get permissions assigned to a role...

Here is an example of my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/roles")
public class RolesController {

    // must use "master" realm and "admin-cli" to connect to the instance
    // although other realms and clients can be modified

    private Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://localhost:8437/auth")
            .realm("master")
            .clientId("admin-cli")
            .username("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .build();

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<RoleRepresentation>> getRoles() throws IOException {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(keycloak.realm("dashing-data").roles().list(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<RoleRepresentation> createRole(@RequestBody RoleRepresentation role) throws IOException {

        List<RoleRepresentation> roleList = keycloak.realm("dashing-data").roles().list();
        boolean roleAlreadyExist = roleList.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.getName().contains(role.getName()));
        RoleRepresentation newRole = new RoleRepresentation();

        if (!roleAlreadyExist){
            newRole.setName(role.getName());
            newRole.setDescription(role.getDescription());
            keycloak.realm("dashing-data").roles().create(newRole);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(newRole, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteRole(@PathVariable String id){

        RoleByIdResource role = keycloak.realm("dashing-data").rolesById();

        if (role == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Could not find the role!", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Role successfully deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are adding complexity where you don't need it. A keycloak Role should be enough for what you are looking for. If you have a CRUD operation that only managers can do (like a DELETE) you simply create a Role in keycloak called "manager" and assign it to the user that you want. In your backend application, you just have to compare the role name to the required role. On the other hand for a Read operation, you can match if the user has the manager or read Role from keycloak.